# parse irregular white space separated textfile

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, text, whitespace

I am trying to parse a **set** of irregularly spaced txt files. 
For a screenshot example see: [Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfE3u.jpg)
The text file looks like this:

```
 Date             This is a              Task       Location                Postal
                     short                                                   code
                 Description
01.01.2000       The weather on this     Take the   Lyon which is a nice    0000123451151 
                 day must have been      Trash out  city. What we do not 
                 very nice. The sun                 know is an opaque 
                 was shining.                       riddle 
02.01.2000       This was a very cold    Eat ice-   Zurich was a nice        0123124 
                 and rainy day. There    cream      trip.
                 must have been some
                 issue with the air-
                 conditioner.
05.01.200        Very rainy day. Sad.    Feel blue  Berlin                   12345
```

I first used:

```
pd.read_table('testfile.txt') #,sep=r"\s*")
```

fails due to:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 5
```

The closest I got using pandas was with fixed separator method:

```
pd.read_fwf('testfile.txt',delim_whitespace=True,skipinitialspace =True,skip_blank_lines=True)
```

This yields the following dataframe: [fwf result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJZba.jpg) where (not surprisingly due to the f in fwf) parts of a string are separated over multiple columns (Note: here this is by construction, it happened in my real world data, too).

Again, elements are **irregularly** white spate separated. That is text testfile.txt first row has different #characters compared to say file2.txt. Thus I can't just count the spaces and apply this to other files.

Visually [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfE3u.jpg) one can see that the **columns** are always separated by white spaces (variable length). I have been working on a (admittedly not very clean) solution: [GitHub](https://github.com/Gand0lf/irregular-white-space-separated-textfile-cleansing)

The idea is to step through the file line by line and replace white space with a delimiter following a heuristic like: "three white spaces followed by non-space character, then replace third white space by delimiter" Then fill delimiter down according to a similar heuristic. The procedure is described in more detail on GitHub.

I would appreciate any tip to solve this problem in a nicer way.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Fortunately for you, this was asked minutes ago.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. I re-phrased my question. I am rather concerned with the irregular white-spacing of the columns across columns and files. Sorry for the imprecise description above. I should have explained the data structure verbally.

Comment: Very concerning... Can you provide a [mcve]. That'll help me discern how the dupe is different from your question, and reopen accordingly.

Comment: Can you post the input file in text form somewhere, so that it's available for processing?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Are you quite sure that this is a dup? The data in this question appears to be amenable to processing using `read_fwf` while that of the other question definitely does not.

Comment: @BillBell it certainly seemed like it until they'd edited. I said I'd reopen  it once they added a [mcve] to their post.

Comment: Hey, I am a busy rn but I will post an example as soon as I can. Coldspeed is right, the original question was not well put pre-edit. If I make some progress myself I will also share it here.

Comment: I have solved my issue with a work around. Nonetheless I think finding a general solution might add value for others as well.